# Differentiate between audio start and audio play(after a pause) in HTML5 <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, html5-audio

How to add a listener on audio/video start?

I can do it like:

```
$audio.on("play", function() {
    console.log("audio played");
});
```

where $audio is a jQuery object representing the single DOM audio element.

but it will also run when we resume the video. I want it to run on start only.

One way I can do it is:

```
$audio.on("play", function() {
  if(this.currentTime === 0) {
      console.log("audio started);
  }
});
```

but this will run multiple times when we play/pause the audio on the start.

Is there any better way to do this? The listener should only work on audio start and audio replayed, **not** when the user manually drags the seek bar to the beginning of the source.

Comment: `var started=false;` - leave the rest for you to figure

Comment: Your method using `currentTime` works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8g4sfj62/ I'm not sure what the issue is. Do you only want to fire the 'started' event once, even if the user manually tracks the audio back to the beginning of the source?

Comment: @freedomn-m I can have n number of players on the same page. So, don't want to maintain those variables.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it is working fine. I am just assuming that let's say user clicked play/pause multiple times in a second. So, I was looking for something which only works when the media started instead of played.

Comment: Then your code is already doing that

Comment: *"I can have n number of players"* - maybe if you included what `$audio` was, that confusion could be quickly averted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also, thanks for this great question. I didn't think it this way. Let's say I want it for start and replay only not when somebody manually tracks the audio back to the beginning of the source.

Comment: @ankur_rajput Please please - [edit] your question. Try to make it sanely clear what you really want. Currently it seems you're totally confused.

Comment: What is "audio replayed" if it is not "user drags seek bar to the beginning" ?

Comment: It could be treated as a second view. We can think it like the user has completely watched the video and now viewing it the second time. Though I agree with the fact that the user can drag the seek bar to the end manually.

Answer (score 1):

Store a flag into the `data-*` attribute of the targeted element:

```js
const $audio = $('.audio');
$audio.on("play", function() {
  
  if ($(this).data('once-played')) return; // Do nothing if data exists.
  
  // Your code here
  console.log("Audio started for the first time");

  // Finally, add a flag.
  $(this).data('once-played', true);
});
```

```html
<audio class="audio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg" autoplay controls loop></audio>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ankur_rajput exactly. Console.log will log only once no matter how many times you play / replay the video (well, unless you refresh the page clearly) - That is based exactly on your question: *"but it will also run when we resume the video. I want it to run on start only"*

Comment: Yes, but I want it to work on every time the video gets started/replayed.

Comment: @ankur_rajput OK than what's wrong in `if(this.currentTime === 0) {` ?? You said in your question *"but this will run multiple times when we play/pause the video on the start"* - Therefore my answer is how it looks right now.

Comment: Then exactly what does checking for currentTime == 0 *not* do?  What's the difference between starting then pausing immediately (so currentTime still = 0, is that even possible?) and starting, watching a bit, rewinding, then starting again?  *Exactly* when do you want this to fire and *exactly* when do you not want it to fire?  Your question+comments are very confused.

Comment: Add an extra check on *pause* - if currentTime != 0 then `$(this).data('once-played', false);`  (maybe reword `once-played` to match this, but the concept is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it might be sounding confusing because I was under the impression that there could be a possibility that currentTime could still return 0 if we do it in a fraction of seconds. But after reading @freedomn-m, @roko-c-buljan, @rory-mccrossan comments, I got it that it will never be possible that currentTime returns 0 when we play-pause-play the video immediately.

Now, let's say I want to track how many times a user has watched the video. The requirements might sound weird but by watched I only meant started/replayed. It doesn't count if the user manually drags the seek bar to the beginning of the source.

Here is how I implemented it finally using all your points:

```
const $audio = $('.audio');
$audio.on("play", function() {

  if ($(this).data('once-played')) return; // Do nothing if data exists.

  // Your code here
  console.log("Audio started/replayed");

  // Finally, add a flag.
  $(this).data('once-played', true);
});

$audio.on("ended", function() {
  $(this).data('once-played', false);
});
```

Comment: But if on `"ended"` you reset data to `false` - this again makes no sense with what you stated in your *edited* question *"The listener should only work on audio start and audio replayed, not when the user manually drags the seek bar to the beginning of the source"* - Listener to what? It's still really hard to understand what you're after, but the `$audio.on("ended", function() {` does not support the question text. Sometimes explaining what you're building and what is the request is more helpful that starting a question with bits and pieces. :|

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem